# A question about the relation between divergence and absolute divergence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Princeton Lectures in Complex Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi says the following:

> If $|z| > R$, then a similar argument proves that there exists a sequence
>   of terms in the series whose absolute value goes to infinity, hence the
>   series diverges.

Why would the fact that $\Sigma{|a_n|}$ diverges imply that $\Sigma{a_n}$ diverges?

Answer (score 1):

That's not what the text says. It says that there is a sequence of *terms* whose absolute value goes to infinity. Recall that a necessary condition for a series to converge is that the terms tend to $0$.